# Force a custom attribute using an interface

Tags: c#

I have an interface called IEntity.

I want all classes that implement this interface to have a class level attribute.

My atttribute is :

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
   public class DbSchemaElementAttribute : System.Attribute
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

How can I ensure if the class is implementing IEntity, it has to have this attribute too.

Is this even possible? Interface is the contract, so it seems like a logical place to enforce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET does not contains methods for forcing derived classes to implement required attribute with check on compile time, both for abstract classes and interfaces.

If you have a requirement to use attributes, so one of possible solutions is to implement unit test for this check, or implement simple check on application start.

But I recommend you to use properties or methods instead of attibutes. So, it's implementation will be easy to check on compile time.